# doesn't work automation autostart command for conky

Tags: xubuntu, autostart, conky

I added conky configuration to my autostart application.

But this doesn't work after I restarted PC.

Here is how looks configuration at setting manager:

[image: conky start]

Here is content of `.ConkyWizardLaunch` file:

> sleep 8 && conky -c ~/.ConkyWizardTheme/ConkyWizardTheme

Another linked file contains exactly conky configuration with looking themas.

It should repaint view every 8 sec.

Unfortunately this doesn't work at start. What is wrong here?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put this in as the <kbd>Command</kbd>:

```
file:///home/nazar/.ConkyWizardLaunch
```

do this one instead

```
/home/nazar/.ConkyWizardLaunch
```

You may need to run `chmod +x /home/nazar/.ConkyWizardLaunch` first to make it executable.

You could also use this, without the need for a script:

```
sleep 8 && conky -c ~/.ConkyWizardTheme/ConkyWizardTheme
```